Kotlin cameraManager.cameraIdList returns only 2 ID'd
I'm setting up a camera in Kotlin using the camera2 API, but I need to use the wide-angle lens of my device. In the code cameraManager.cameraIdList only returns the id [0, 1] referring to the rear and front cameras. Searching for physical cameras characteristics.physicalCameraIds in id 0, I get an empty return, I wanted to know what I might be doing wrong.
Device used is a Poco x3 PRO.
Sdk = 30
private fun openCamera() {
        try {
            val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0] ?: return
            val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
            val capabilities = characteristics.physicalCameraIds
            Log.d(TAG, "capabilities: $capabilities")
            previewSize = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!
                .getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture::class.java)[0]
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return
            }
            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice = camera
                    createCameraPreviewSession()
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    camera.close()
                }

                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                    camera.close()
                }
            }, null)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

I've tried setting the zoom to 0.6 as I saw in some places, I've also tried putting IDs that aren't in the list. All without success.

On my G100 device, a zoom of 0.8 is the least which works... these values might vary, depending on the hardware. For reference: https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_poco_x3_pro-10802.php ...while your question is anything but clear, because there are indeed only two cameras. Why you don't use CameraX?

I understand that my question may have been confusing.
What I meant is that in the identified IDs [0,1], they refer to the front and rear cameras.
However, in the rear camera I cannot identify the wide-angle camera, only the normal camera.
As I said, I have already tried to set the zoom to values ​​below 1 and search for physical IDs present within ID 0.
I can't use cameraX because I need to manipulate the capture time.
I apologize for my English.

This wide-angle lens likely is still the same camera device; you'd have to determine it's capabilities: https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camera2/camera-enumeration
